# Dynamically switching between properties files based on request header parameter in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am developing an multi-tenant REST spring boot application. I am able to dynamically switch between different data-sources based on a header value in every request. But my problem is on the application.properties file. The different tenants have different values for the same properties in their properties files.

How can I separate the properties files per tenant and also dynamically determine which properties files to use based on a value in the request header

Comment: You could use profiles and have one file per tenant. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html Are you able to determine which tenant is calling with the header?

Comment: Yes, I am able to identify the tenant based on the header sent in the request. I have reviewed profiles but I am not clear how a class can switch profiles based on the request header value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't switch profiles at runtime. Your options are limited to either creating a new `ApplicationContext` which comes with its own drawbacks or you can load the tenant property files at startup and implement a tenant-specific `getProperty` method to call when needed.

This ought-to handle the latter case:

```
@Component
public class TenantProperties {

  private Map<String, ConfigurableEnvironment> customEnvs;

  @Inject
  public TenantProperties(@Autowired ConfigurableEnvironment defaultEnv,
      @Value("${my.tenant.names}") List<String> tenantNames) {

    this.customEnvs = tenantNames
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Function.identity(),
            tenantId -> {
              ConfigurableEnvironment customEnv = new StandardEnvironment();
              customEnv.merge(defaultEnv);
              Resource resource = new ClassPathResource(tenantId + ".properties");

              try {
                Properties props = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
                customEnv.getPropertySources()
                    .addLast(new PropertiesPropertySource(tenantId, props));
                return customEnv;
              } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
              }
            }));
  }

  public String getProperty(String tenantId, String propertyName) {

    ConfigurableEnvironment ce = this.customEnvs.get(tenantId);
    if (ce == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid tenant");
    }

    return ce.getProperty(propertyName);
  }
}
```

You need to add a `my.tenant.names` property to your main application properties that contains a comma separated list of tenant names (`name1, name2`, etc.). tenant-specific properties are loaded from `name1.properties`, ... from the classpath. You get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Spring profiles would work in your case.

If tenants are static in the sense predictive tenants and its properties only before starting the service then I would suggest tovgo for static profile specific files.

If some of properties can be changed whilst service is serving for other tenants, then it would be good to go for config server so that without restart you can change those.

If tenants are dynamic, you can go for db based on your data points, if tenants count may increase substantially.

Comment: The tenants are static. I like the config server option and have been exploring that. But I am unclear how the application would switch between the different profiles for each tenant